# Aumentar altura da linha de um gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: c#, grid

Senhores(as),

tenho um gridcontrol do devexpress(12.1) sendo preenchido por uma lista, e preciso aumentar a linha, se o texto for maior, e preciso fazer isso dinamicamente(se o texto couber na largura, não preciso quebrar a linha).

[image: print da grid do devexpress]

Já tentei as propriedades "wrap" pra tentar quebrar a linha, mas não tive sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a versão 13.2 e o código abaixo ocorreu a quebra de linha corretamente.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Dado1">
            <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Na verdade a grid que me refiro está em um windows form, já que a aplicação é desktop. Tentei usar a propriedade "wrap" nas várias propriedades possíveis relacionadas a texto. Ainda assim não foi possível...

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A8

Comment: Esse link da devexpress vai ajudar. Abraço

Comment: O que eu precisava fazer era marcar a propriedade do campo que precisava de quebra com RowAutoHeight = true, e adicionar um memoEdit no campo, por dentro do designer do DevExpress. Link da solução: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q376637 Já consegui implementar certinho. Obrigado @Eugenio Spolti